# HTML form inside modal POST is working but not writing to database Django

Tags: html, django-views, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I am new to the Django framework. I have developed a page with a table and Add button. When the Add button clicks, it will open the form inside a modal. Here the problem is when I first tried, the data in the form filled to the table as expected. But after, when I did the same thing, it gave 200 for POST, and nothing filled in the table. And no errors showing.

This is my sample code.

```
<!--modal for Create record-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <form method="POST" class="modal-dialog modal-md" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"><strong>Add Company</strong></h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="companyName" class="col-12 col-md-4"><strong>Company Name</strong></label>
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" name="companyName" placeholder="Company Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="address" class="col-12 col-md-4"><strong>Address</strong></label>
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            <button type="close" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And here is the code in views.py

```
def addcompany(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('companyName') and request.POST.get('address'):
            saverecord = company()
            saverecord.CompanyName = request.POST.get('company')
            saverecord.Address = request.POST.get('address')
            saverecord.save()
            return render(request, 'newapp/companypage.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'newapp/companypage.html')
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error in the company name  you should write it like this:

```py
            saverecord.CompanyName = request.POST.get('companyName')
```

You can also read more about how to build [forms from models with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Yes. It was an issue. Thank you @Ali Ibrahim for your great help. And I found another error when link to the views file. Now the form is working fine.